# angular HttpModule how to handle inappropriate received data from a remote API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am fetching data from remote API via Angular like this:

```
this.http.get("https://example.com/getUsers").subscribe(users => {
  this.users = users.json();
});
```

And in HTML component:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let x of users; let i = index">
    {{x.id}} {{x.body}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now when data is structured as it should be - array of json encoded documents, every thing is okay.

But if remote data structure will be changed from:

```
[
 {
   // some object
 }
]
```

To

```
"just a string"
```

The app probably will be shut down due to two errors:

1. data received is not longer a valid json format.
2. ngFor will be caused since its not an array.

How to solve this?

Comment: Well, if you change what a web service returns, make sure to also change the clients using that service (i.e. your Angular app). If you did forget, then fix the bug when you realize there is one.

Comment: And if this is a web service to a remote API which is not mine?

Comment: Well, don't use such a bad remote API that would change what it does without even warning its users, nor without writing a different version of the web service and leaving the current version unchanged. If you have no choice, then, for example, write some tests run on a regular basisto check that the API still returns what it should.

Comment: @Kalamarico why did you remove the `[JavaScript]` and `[Serialization]` tags?

Comment: @AluanHaddad correct me if I'm wrong but, this is typescript not javascript (we know that both have the same origin) and the main problem here is not the serialization, the main problem refers to http request and catch the error

Comment: @Kalamarico the second point is arguable but I completely disagree with you on the first. It's not a matter of having the same origin, it's a matter of one literally being a superset of the other. This isn't about types and so it falls in the superset. The code in the question is JavaScript. That's what both you and the OP are programming in

Comment: I assume as he is using angular, he is using typescript, but in fact you are right, sorry for that, your reasoning is correct, so my fault for removing javascript tag

Answer (score 1):

In subscribe you are catching the onNext but you need to catch the onError too:

```
this.http.get("https://example.com/getUsers").subscribe(
  users => {
    this.users = users.json();
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.users = [];
  }
);
```

[Here](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html) you have more detail info about subscribe.

By the way if your problem is, that the response is catched in the onNext and the problem is 'users' is not an array, you can check before:

```
this.http.get("https://example.com/getUsers").subscribe(
  users => {
    // Check if users is an array, but you may check whatever you need.
    if (Array.isArray(users)) {
      this.users = users.json();
    } else {
      this.users = [];
    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.users = [];
  }
);
```

There are two http headers that you need to know, first, there is a htpp request header called `"Accept"`, this header specify the mimetype that you will be accept, for example if you set the request header `"Accept: application/json"` before doing the http get, when the backend take the request and "did his job", it will be set a http response header called `"Content-Type"`, this header specify the mimetype of the response body. If the `"Accept"` request header is not the same of `"Content-Type"` response header, it will be catched by OnError.

Probably you are not specify the `Accept` header, so whatever the mimetype has the response body it will be catched by the onNext.

Comment: It's unusual to use the angular HTTP client in a view directly. I know that the question does just that but it might be worth going into the common case and using `Observable.prototype.catch`

Comment: The best approach should be using the async pipe in the *ngFor but if he is using that way, his problem solves with this

Comment: That's an excellent point. That is the best approach. I wish more people did that instead of (as usual) writing too much code.

Comment: Check my answer again, I have changed